# Basic Tutorial? Makefiles in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, linker, makefile, eclipse-cdt

Does anyone know where a **good** tutorial exists for making an Eclipse CDT C project? I've seen a couple on C++, but none of them describe what I need to know as an absolute beginner of the plug-in and of C programming in general:

1. When I build the project, nothing happens. Why?
2. When I add 'make targets' by right clicking files and adding the file name and an output file name, it will compile those files, but there are undefined reference errors (and before you tell me, YES I have looked those up on many SO questions and many other websites, but I have not found any solutions that address the problem in the context of CDT). Why are there linker errors, and what do I need to do to make the makefile simply compile my code as I would (e.g. "gcc -Wall source1.c source2.c -o client") in proper order so as not to produce the linker errors?

Any help will be much appreciated. I feel like Eclipse CDT is some kind of cryptic Pandora's box that whenever I open it unleashes chaos onto my programming universe because of the apparent lack of straight-forward beginner tutorials. Thank you in advance for any direction you could give.

Comment: I would also be interested in the answer to this question

Comment: Did you try this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecc/?S_TACT=105AGX44&S_CMP=ART ?

Comment: I have looked at the IBM tutorial, even though it is C++. I appreciate your providing the older version which has a little more specific info, but even following its guidelines in C does not work (makefile still does not know what to do even after running the auto-generated ./configure in the Hello World example project that Eclipse CDT comes with)  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be of some help for you:

www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~eclipse/7-EclipseCDT.pdf